# How to convert the filetype from .png to .mha?

Tags: image-segmentation

I am doing brain tumor segmentation with the BTATS2013. I have gotten the test result with the testing dataset of BRATS 2013 which don't have ground truth, so I can't get the Dice, PPV, Sensitivity directly. I want to use [the online platform](https://www.smir.ch/Home/Browse) to evaluate the segmentations, it requires the filetype of input is `.mha`, but the filetype of segmentations that I get is `.png`. I don't know how to convert the `.png` to `.mha`. Is there anyone can help me to solve the problem, or can you give me some advice of getting the indicators of segmentation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Load your data in 3DSlicer,
You can load Png files there. 
Then store it in mha format:

[image: Loading the PNG file]

[image: Exporting the file in MHA format]